# UnicodeDecodeError in python exifread.process_file

Tags: python, metadata, jpeg, exif

Python Grammar Version 3.0 using PyDev in Eclipse Mars

I'm trying to use exifread to extract exif metadata from JPG images.

Got this error:

```
tags = exifread.process_file(img.open())
File "<PATH REDACTED>\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\exifread\__init__.py", line 31, in process_file
    data = f.read(12)
    File "<PATH REDACTED>\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode  
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 386: character maps to <undefined>
```

I've tried utf-8, ascii, and a couple other random codecs just hoping to get lucky.  Any ideas/help in getting this working?

Comment: have you tried cp1252 encoding?

Comment: Can you upload a sample image somewhere, without loss of information so that someone can inspect the given file meta data?

Comment: Latin-1 did it.  Thanks!

Comment: I see this on many different images.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're opening the file in binary mode:

```py
import exifread
f = open(path_name, 'rb') # 'rb' = read, binary
tags = exifread.process_file(f)
```

No idea if that's the same issue though as this is an old question and there isn't really any code.